# What is the best way to add cors or headers in apollo server4 with azure integration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, azure-functions, apollo-server

I am facing an issue in cors. We are not able to *allow* the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Please let us know how to add the headers or how to handle the Cors issue.
Below added my code snippet.

```
const { ApolloServer } = require('@apollo/server');
const { startServerAndCreateHandler } = require('@as-integrations/azure-functions');
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  csrfPrevention: false, 
});
exports.graphqlHandler = startServerAndCreateHandler(server);
```

Thanks in advance :)

We are trying to solve the cors issue in apollo server 4 with azure integration.

Comment: search for CORS in the documentation for `apollo/server`

Comment: Check this [document](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/security/cors/) @vasanthsp

Comment: There is no document for Azure integration

Answer (score 0):

- ***To add CORS in Apollo Server Azure functions, you need define CORS while Instantiating the Server as shown below:***

```js
const server = new ApolloServer({
    cors: {
        origin: '*',// '*' refers to allow request from all domains
        credentials: true
    },
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  csrfPrevention: false, 
});
```

***My Code Sinppet:***

```js
const { ApolloServer, gql } =  require('apollo-server-azure-functions');
const { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault } =  require('apollo-server-core');

const  typeDefs  =  gql`
    type Query {
    hello: String
    }
`;

const  resolvers  = {
        Query: {
            hello: () =>  'Hello world!',
    },
};

const  server  =  new  ApolloServer({
 cors: {
    origin: '*',        
    credentials: true
},
typeDefs, 
resolvers, 
csrfPrevention:  true, 
cache:  'bounded',
plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault({ embed:  true }),],});

exports.graphqlHandler  =  server.createHandler();
```

**Response:**

[image]

[image]

**References:**

[How to enable CORS for apollo-server](https://www.rockyourcode.com/how-to-enable-cors-for-apollo-server/)